# How can I disable free shipping for particular states?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to disable the free shipping method when the total of greater than $50 and the country is USA, but for some States (Alaska, Guam, Puerto Rico, Hawaii) this shipping method should be disabled.

I have setup the shipping for the USA set the minimum amount to $50, but do not know how to disable on these 4 states Alaska, Guam, Puerto Rico, Hawaii.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've seen in the `wc-class-free-shipping.php`

```
function is_available($package)
{
    //added this line
    if($package['destination']['state'] == 'AK')
        return false;
}
```

Worked perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

Under the shipping tab in the Woocommerce settings there is an tab called Free Shipping. Select `specific countries` and you can then allow the countries that you want and disallow the countries that you dont!

Comment: Hi,

Thanks For reply. As you said i have done with it. But want to disable this shipping method on the some of states of the selected country.
Like i have selected this method to be available on the USA. But want to disable on the some of states of USA.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_' . $this->id . '_is_available', true );
```

Source: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/977

This should help you. Haven't tried it as I was looking for the same thing!