# Custom free shipping for only UK and a specific product in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, country

I have been trying to create a Free Shipping option for a client's promotional product that will be shipped worldwide but will only have Free Shipping option for orders from the UK. So when someone orders from the USA or Hong Kong, the usual rate will be applied. But somehow, I can't exclude these countries from Shipping Class. (I am not using Free Shipping Method because when I try, it applies to all products, that's why I created a Shipping Class for this)

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you share some code? If possible follow the [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use shipping methods on your specific product for that particular case. Instead this custom function below will do the trick, defining your specific product id in it.

When a customer from UK **adds only** your specific product to cart, the code will rename your flat rate shipping method to "Free shipping" setting the cost to ZERO.

> To test that code, you should first **enable the debug mode** in Woocommerce shipping settings under "Shipping options" tab.

Also you will have to do again your settings for the "flat rate" shipping method, or to remove the shipping class from your specific product.

The code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'disable_shipping_methods', 20, 2 );
function disable_shipping_methods( $rates, $package ) {
    // ==> HERE set your targeted product IDs in a coma separated array
    $products_ids = array(37);

    if( ! ( isset($package['destination']['country']) && isset($package['contents']) ) )
        return $rates; // If 'destination' country is not defined, we exit

    // Only for United kingdom customers
    if( $package['destination']['country'] != 'GB' )
        return $rates; // Non UK customers we exit.

    // Loop through cart items and checking if there is any other products than the targeted ones
    $found = false;
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ) {
        if( in_array( $item['data']->get_id(), $products_ids ) ){
            $found = true;
        } else {
            return $rates; // Other items found in cart, we exit.
        }
    }

    // When the customer is in UK and the target product is alone in cart we set the flat rate price to zero.
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        // Targetting flat rate method
        if( $rate->method_id == 'flat_rate' && $found ){
            // We change the shipping label name
            $rates[$rate_key]->label = __("Free shipping", "woocommerce");

            // Set the rate cost to zero
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = 0;

            // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
            $taxes = array();
            foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $rates[$rate_key]->taxes[$key] > 0 ){
                    $taxes[$key] = 0;
                    $has_taxes = true;
                }
            }
            if( isset($has_taxes) && $has_taxes )
                $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Customer form UK with this unique item in cart - **Free shipping**

[image]

Customer form UK with this item and others in cart - **Normal shipping**

[image]

Customer from other countries  with this unique item in cart - **Normal shipping**

[image]

> Once you get that working, don't forget to disable the debug mode  in Woocommerce shipping settings under "Shipping options" tab.

Comment: Thanks! will also try it but for now just changed the code line in functions.php and it worked.                                                                
  
   if ( in_array( $item['data']->get_shipping_class(), $eligible ) ) {  
    if ( in_array( $customerfff, $eligible ) ) {
     // this item doesn't have the right class. return default availability
     print("<script>console.log('gb free');</script>");
     return $is_available;  (this line was : // nothing out of the ordinary return true
  return true; )

Answer (score 0):

[image: Shipping Class]

Sorry for the german screenshot but is that not possible to set up shipping zones & shipping classes?
You could set up 2 shipping zones: UK & the rest of the world and add the shipping classes like you want for your products. If you try this and it still doesnt work, could you attach some code samples?

Comment: Hi, no that also creates a free shipping option for other products. only one product should have the free shipping option and this option should be available only for the UK. That's why I created a shipping class and write a code in functions.php, whenever that shipping class is enabled for a product, only this product will have that option. now I also need to exclude countries. :((

Comment: If you dont have many products in your database, you should define a shipping method for every product. Maybe this would solve your issue.
Or just try to work with this sample code?
http://www.boopathirajan.com/remove-specific-country-woocommerce-country-list/

Comment: I have like +30 products, besides the code you shared is to exclude countries from the shipping list, not from the shipping method. :( but again thanks, I will try to modify this code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379757/woocommerce-exclude-state-free-shipping-australian-states , if there is any luck, I will share :)